# how to extend lua metatables with (something like) __index

Tags: lua

The following session shows what I was trying to.  I must have misread some documentation somewhere that (I thought) said that an __index item in a metatable provides a default when the table doesn't provide an item for that key.  The point is it doesn't work on metatables themselves but I have no idea why not.  Where in the documentation is this explained, and what can I do about it in such cases?

Thanks!

```
> a = {}
> b = {}
> setmetatable(a,b)
table: 0000000002631ae0
> c = { __tostring = function(x) return "X" end }
> setmetatable(b,{ __index=c })
table: 0000000002631560
>
> print(a)
table: 0000000002631ae0
> -- I was expecting: X
> print(getmetatable(a).__tostring)
function: 0000000002633840
> print(tostring(a))
table: 0000000002631ae0
> -- Again, expecting X
> print(getmetatable(a).__tostring(a))
X
>
```

Here is another example.

```
> a = {}
> b = {}
> setmetatable(a,b)
table: 0000000002631fe0
> c = { __add = function(x,y) return "X" end }
> setmetatable(b,{ __index=c })
table: 00000000026316a0
>
> print(a+a)
stdin:1: attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value (global 'a')
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
>
```

So this problem is not specific to print and tostring.  Of course in real situations I want to have a lot of different objects sharing a lot of metatable values without having to copy everything every time...

Answer (score 1):

This is because `__index` is related to indexing operations like `tbl.var`. Lua doesn't use `__index` to get other metamethod (like `__tostring`).

You are using `print` which invokes `__tostring` directly from the metatable, it doesn't use `__index` here.

> __index: The indexing access operation **table[key]**
>
> Learn more: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4

The solution would merging metatable `c` with `b`.

```lua
setmetatable(b,{ __tostring = c.__tostring })
print(b) -- X
```

Comment: I don't know where tbl.var is described.  But it's not specific to print and __tostring.  I added another example...

Comment: @SadieKaye Ok, little rephrasing, Lua doesn't use __index to get other metamethods. This affects __tostring, __add, __sub, __mul, __mode, __pairs, etc (all of them)

Comment: OK so the questions are .. where is this documented and what do I do about it?

Comment: @SadieKaye It's not documented specifically, but it mentions when __index is invoked.
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4

> __index: The indexing access operation "table[key]"

Comment: OK .. the documentation is still not clear if it is done recursively (as I had assumed) or directly (as seems to be). Disappointing.  And I still don't see how I can inherit all these (many) methods in the metatables without direct copying and serious and stupid blow-up

Comment: @SadieKaye You have no other choice but to copy metamethods into each object. They don't inherit because there is no rule for inheritance.

Comment: @SadieKaye: It's documented [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4). "Lua queries metamethods in metatables using a raw access (see rawget)."

Comment: It's annoying that it doesn't work, but it's a reasonable compromise considering performance.

Comment: Thanks luther .. yes that sentence seems clear.  Yes rather annoying... I have changed my code to copy everything now.